# Как сделать исполняемый файл(exe) из своей программы написаной на java, не требующий от пользователя установленной java?

Tags: java, exe

Вообщем хочу сделать свое приложение запускаемым, на компьютере где ничего не установлено. Чтобы программа работала вообще на (чистой) windows, и не требовала от юзера, чтобы он устанавливал дополнитеьлное ПО.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/147233/7129209

Answer (score 2):

руками можно сделать командный файл и приложение не будет требовать установленной java, но jre необходимо положить

например так:

структура папок:

[общая папка приложения]
├[папка с jre]
├[папка с jar]
└start.bat

код bat файла:

```
[папка с jre]\bin\java -jar [папка с jar]\MyJar.jar
```

так же в intellij idea приложение javafx можно скомпилировать в запускаемый exe

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь утилитой https://www.excelsiorjet.com/# Это довольно удобная программа, которая позволит вам создать инсталятор для вашего приложения, и позволит запускать его без наличия jre, доп. библиотек и т.д. на компьютере. Там есть еще пару доп. фишек, вроде защиты от reverse engineering и т.д. Доступна триальная версия на 30 дней.